# "The" or "a" with "that"

Tags: articles, nouns

From Tom Odell, *Another Love*:

> And I'd sing ***a*** song that'd be just ours.

Shouldn't the article “the” stand in this case? is it explained here that this song will be only ours?

And the word "that" gives any advantage to putting the article "the", not only in this sentence but also in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is any one of many songs *until* it becomes *just ours*. Afterwards, it would make sense to say, "That is our song." Note the word `that'd`, short for `that would`, in the hypothetical future.

Comment: And in such a proposal will it be correct to put "the"?
And I sing the song that is ours.

Comment: @Boyep - It woudn't be incorrect, but it isn't necessary, either.

Comment: @J.R. If it's not difficult for you, can you give me an example of where the article will be necessary?

Comment: @Boyep - _Let's sing the song that we heard yesterday._ (Assuming we only listened to one song yesterday, the correct article would be **the**. However, if we had listened to several, we could use **a** instead: _Let's sing a song that we heard yesterday._)